# Abelian extensions of Q and cyclotomic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields, field-extensions

I have changed some notation based on the comments of Chris Wuthrich and Wojowu.

For an abelian extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, let $c(F)$ be its conductor. That is, $c(F)$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $F$ is contained in the $n$-th cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(e_n):=\mathbb{Q}(\exp(2i\pi/n))$. Let $p$ be a prime and $p^k$ be the $p$-part of $c(F)$. That is, $k$ is the p-adic valuation of $c(F)$.

I am trying to find examples and understand the structure of those $F$ with $k$ large but $\mathbb{Q}(e_{p^k}) \cap F(e_p)$ small. (Here, $F(e_p)$ is the field generated by $F$ and $e_p=\exp(2i\pi/p)$.)

An explicit question: what are the fields $F$ with $\mathbb{Q}(e_{p^k})\cap F(e_p)=\mathbb{Q}(e_p)$ (smallest possible case) and $k$ arbitrarily large?

Or, what are the fields $F$ with $\mathbb{Q}(e_{p^k})\cap F(e_p)=\mathbb{Q}(e_{p^2})$ and $k$ arbitrarily large?

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{Q}_p $ for a field other than the $p$-adics is confusing.

Comment: What is $\mathbb Q_p(F)$? The compositum $\mathbb Q_pF$?

Comment: There are infinitely many extensions $F$ of $\mathbf{Q}$ of degree $p$ and conductor exactly divisible by $p^2$. For all but one of them, the intersection of $F(\zeta_p) \cap \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})$ is $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)$. So what exactly is the question in this case? Do you want to see how to construct them? (Take $q \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and take any of the $p+1$ degree $p$ extensions inside $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{p^2 q})$ besides the two extensions which are either unramified at $p$ or $q$). The general problem as far as I can guess what is being asked is hardly any different from this.